# Unable to Declare in variable in new java class in android

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

I am developing an Android application. In `MainActivity` I have a `button`. `On Button Click` it takes me to new page (`New Java Class`). In `new java class` I am declaring another button and `TextField` like:

```
EditText RandomNumber;
 Button response;
```

But it is giving me errors in `EditText` and `Button "Syntax error in EditText and Button,import expected"`

I already have import files in my new class.
I didn't find anything related to this in stackoverflow..

Comment: There is no code example or real question asked. So, what is it that you want from SO?

Comment: Post your code sample or take a snapshot of error you're getting and include it along with this question

Comment: this seems to be a plain java syntax issue. please read up on that. without code samples we can't help you any further.

Answer (score 0):

you need to import the ditText and Button classes.

just add after the package declaretion:

```
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Button;
```

Comment: try to change the name of the EditText